# defining header as a tag in jquery ui accordian

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

see the following

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUbMb/8/)

I have an accordian with the header defined as a.viewLabel. My aim is to have another class which will link to an external page. But you will see in the fiddle that defining the header cause the accordion to behave strangely

```
 $("#main-nav").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
     header: 'a.viewLabel'
});
```

Comment: every a is viewLabel in you code

Answer (score 0):

The inner accordion is treated as part of the original accordion because the selector finds all the elements that match your selector regardless of where they are located inside the DOM tree of the element you instantiate on.

I would suggest to separate the inner accordion with different classes and to instantiate a new accordion inside.

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUbMb/15/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="" class="viewLabel">item one</a>
        <ul id="new">
            <li><a href="" class="viewLabel1">item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="viewLabel1">item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="viewLabel1">item one</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" class="viewLabel">item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="viewLabel">item one</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$("#main-nav").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    header: 'a.viewLabel'
});

$("#new").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    header: 'a.viewLabel1'
});
```